# How can I style my editText as a spinner? Support to Lollipop not working

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library

I have one EditText field that I want to stylize as a Spinner, and Im using the support library to Android Lollipop. However, I'm not able to give the correct color to the dropdown selector (the same that is used on the default spinner) .

The example can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9xF0.jpg

I want a darker selector, but I'm only able to get a white selector as it can be seen in the image (the first one is my editText as a spinner, with the white selector, and the second one is the real spinner, with the darker and corrector selector)

How can I change that color?

The style of the activity is this one:

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/h19_black</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The style of my EditText is the following:

```
 <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_birth_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:focusable="false"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"  />
```

Any ideas? I've been struggling for a while with this. I have no more ideas.

Thank you!!

Comment: How did you style your EditText? How did you add that spinner arrow?

Comment: @AlexandruRosianu edited the post with the EditText style. The spinner arrow appears with that android style.

Comment: You want a spinner, but you are using a editText?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I want the style of the spinner, but I want to be able to add another behavior and a click listener. So that's the reason for having an editText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!

The AppCompat library doesn't seem to have a black version of the arrow, so what you have to do is take the white version and change the colour manually. The file name is `abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png` and you can find it [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/appcompat/res). There's one in each `drawable-*` folder (10 of them).

Then just add this attribute to your EditText:

```
android:background="@drawable/spinner_arrow_black"
```

You can also do this programmatically, maintaining you spinner style and without playing with the drawable files:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: Im using api 15 as my minimum. I'm not able to do it!